# Cauchy's inequalities in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying some notes I've been given by my teacher and I believe there is a mistake.

It says in the notes that if $g$ is holomorphic in $D(0,r)$ and $|g(z)| \le M$ for all $z \in D(0,r)$ then by Cauchy's integral formula we have

$|g'(ζ)| \le$ $2M \over r$ for all $ζ \le$$r \over 2$

That doesn't seem right to me. I know this is true for $ζ=0$ but I can't make the aforementioned deduction. At least not with Cauchy's formula

Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. First, the result you state is not the usual Cauchy's estimate; it follows from it. To see this, apply the basic Cauchy on the disc $D(\zeta,r/2).$

Comment: Yeah I see it. Thanks